# How to append strings to the same line instead of creating a new line?

Tags: bash, redirect

Redirection to a file is very usefull to append a string as a new line to a file, like

```
echo "foo" >> file.txt
echo "bar" >> file.txt
```

Result:

```
foo
bar
```

But is it also possible to redirect a string to the same line in the file ?

Example:

```
echo "foo" <redirection-command-for-same-line> file.txt
echo "bar" <redirection-command-for-same-line> file.txt
```

Result:

```
foobar
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The newline is added by `echo`, not by the redirection. Just pass the `-n` switch to `echo` to suppress it:

```
echo -n "foo" >> file.txt
echo -n "bar" >> file.txt
```

> `-n`     do not output the trailing newline

Comment: This worked well. Although one has  to be careful that there are no 'empty lines' at the end of a file.

Comment: When run these two command and open file.txt it contains:
---------------------------------
-n "foo" 
-n "bar" 
---------------------------------
Each on a new line, but SO replies don't seem to allow new lines.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way to echo results to one line would be to simply assign the results to variables. Example:

```
j=$(echo foo)
i=$(echo bar)
echo $j$i
foobar
echo $i $j
bar foo
```

This is particularly useful when you have more complex functions, maybe a complex 'awk' statement to pull out a particular cell in a row, then pair it with another set.